# Set OpenGL sample position

Tags: opengl

Is it possible to change the sample position for the OpenGL rasterisation from (0.5, 0.5) to something else? (I am referring to the sample position used when rendering without any multisampling etc.)

The reason is that I would like to implement anti aliasing by blending multiple render results together with different sample positions. I would then need variables coming from the vertex shader to be interpolated to different positions within the pixel.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dedicated GL extension (https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/sample_locations.txt)  if your driver support it.

Comment: Thank you, but the specification says:

"Should programmable sample locations affect non-multisample rendering?

RESOLVED: No, the programmable sample locations only apply to multisample rasterization rules. "

Comment: Don't you combine multiple images in a multisampled buffer? Indeed, how do you perform antialiasing without combining multie samples within the same pixel?

Comment: In other cases, it sufficient to translate the model-view matrix by a fraction of a pixel to sample textured primitives at different positions.

Comment: I think that you are right. I was under the impression that pixels would end up sampling the same texture position (for example) even if I shift the vertices by a sub-pixel amount by modifying the transformation matrix, but I guess that the UV's would be different then even if the sample position still is at the center of the pixel.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to include what you wrote in your comment about translating the matrix so that I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: I will when I'll get back at home ;)

Comment: "In other cases, it sufficient to translate the model-view matrix by a fraction of a pixel to sample textured primitives at different positions." Just to complete this comment, this is how TXAA works (like any temporal filter)